# What does keyof in array in return type mean?

Tags: typescript

I found this TypeScript construct in the source code of a colleague:

```js
protected getData(): { [item in keyof Fruit]: any; } {
    return {
      color: [],
      tree: [],
    };
}
```

I don't understand the return-type definition in the signature: `{ [item in keyof Fruit]: any; }`

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getData` returns an object. If we assume that there's a key in that object named `item` then `item` must be `in` the type `keyof Fruit`. If the type `Fruit` has distinct keys defined then the type `keyof Fruit` is a union type of each of those keys.

The way this return type is defined uses an [index signature](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures#declaring-an-index-signature) type

For example:

```
interface Fruit {
  color: string;
  tree: string;
}

type FruitKeys = keyof Fruit; // 'color'|'tree'

type Return = { 
   // item is either 'color' or 'tree'
   [item in FruitKeys]: any; // This is an index signature defining how this type can be indexed.
}

const a : Return = {
  color: 'aaa', 
  tree: null,
  abc: '' // error abc not in the keys of Fruit
}
```

A shorter way of defining this would have been to use the [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) utility type. In this case it's shorter to write:

```
function getData(): Record<keyof Fruit, any> {
    return  {
      color: [], 
      tree: [],
    };
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGJQK7DMg3gKGWQQHsAbEqALmQGcwpQBzAbkOQYghvsZFfwBffPjABPAA4p0WMAGkIY2sgC8yANaKSMNJmwtkAekPIA5KQpRTAH1OcIpkeKnIAShDAYoIVXmTsjE2wIAFtkYGUIbAALaDMLSlNkSjN7RyJkAG1gsNBdWQUlAF0aOBAxA2NkABVoiPDlMvCQABMIAA86YCYQOE8oFDaYUGZkaJIAdw465WcUBCaAIxRQNvaIFoA6IRFSEHpkOGQad36fNQIiBOozODvTABp-InsaEAwyMgf2OEWEGlMSSq0CgKV+CGQIBIODyYFiGkUym0+WwO3wMAwIAQYGAJB8TA8ABE+nAABQAShOEFIUBaAB5NGJkTJsE8ymIAHx4ALIAZnIiXDJXciUAF3OCPZ5CjgDbiQj5fHlEcEAoEmEFgv6Q6HNaYoRlInQssA8wRsQRAA)